# Troubleshooting Signed XML

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, cryptography

Please help:
The vendor requires a signed xml and doesn't provide much help describing how to properly sign the xml.  I'm sending the following xml:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference Id="_2"><wsse:Reference URI="#binarytoken" /></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" ValueType="wsse:X509v3" wsu:Id="binarytoken">removed for security</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI="#_2"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>b3U301pqu017IPMBNIZ04dybZ+A=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#_1"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>NLpGjn8jJ7RI/R4rVdiwZPRRyMU=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>some signed value here</SignatureValue></Signature></wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="_1"><msg:CompanyMessage xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:msg="companyNameSpace"><msg:Header><msg:Verb>get</msg:Verb><msg:Noun>CompanyFunction</msg:Noun><msg:Revision>1</msg:Revision><msg:Source>COMPANY</msg:Source><msg:UserID>USER</msg:UserID><msg:MessageID>123456789</msg:MessageID><msg:ReplayDetection><wsu:Created>2018-07-27T02:20:39-05:00</wsu:Created><wsse:Nonce>65b9a415-19d9-4090-8520-e1de12cc9721</wsse:Nonce></msg:ReplayDetection></msg:Header></msg:CompanyMessage></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and I'm receiving an error that states there is a soap fault SECU3504: Digital Signature verification failure.  Validity of ds:Signed Info's signature: java.lang.NullPointerException.  Validaty of Signature references: #_2: true. #_1: false.

It reads like there is an issue with how I'm referencing the envelope body Id="_1".

Here is the c# code I use to sign the xml after I've created the body and security token reference in the header.

```
        SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(doc);

        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;

        Reference CertRefSign = new Reference { Uri = "#" + SecurityTokenReference };
        CertRefSign.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";
        CertRefSign.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        signedXml.AddReference(CertRefSign);

        Reference BodySign = new Reference { Uri = "#" + EnvelopeBodyId };
        BodySign.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";
        BodySign.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        signedXml.AddReference(BodySign);

        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement signedElement = signedXml.GetXml();
        ErcotHeaderSecurityXml.AppendChild(signedElement);
```

Any assistance is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was working for a telecom operator, we have similar services that use WS-Security that need the signature. When i need to test these services, i faced the same problem. of course, our partners are also feel pain to use these services.

Finally, I got it work by using WCF (you need as least .NET framework 4.0):

First step, you need to import the Web Service Description from the provided WSDL, and make this changes on the generated code:

You must add `ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign` to the `ServiceContratAttribute` to tell the WCF you need to sign it:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign, Namespace="http://ServiceProvider.someTelecom.fr/Services/Payment "
public interface GetPaymentPortType
{
…
}
```

Then you should use the following customBinding in app.config

```
   <customBinding>
    <binding name="HTTPBinding_WSSecurity">
     <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
      requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
      <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:10:00" />
      <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:10:00" />
      <secureConversationBootstrap />
     </security>
     <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
     <httpTransport />
    </binding>
    </customBinding>
```

Finally, before call the web serivce, you need also to load your Client Certificate (following code in .pfx format) inorder to Sign the soap message.

```
//Load the signature certificate
X509Certificate2 mycertificate = new X509Certificate2("SignatureCertificate.pfx", "[pfx protection password]");

//Create the wcf client from the given binding
MyServicePortTypeClient client = new MyServicePortTypeClient("HTTPBinding_WSSecurity");
client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://xxxxxx/myService"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("dns_name"));
//set the client ceritificate
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = mycertificate;
//Call the service
client.Payment(xxx);
```

Bonus:
If you are using self-signed certificate, make sure that the certificate can be validated on the server of your service provider. otherwise, you should use the certificate privided by the provider.

Comment: That was my first attempt.  The vendor blocks the wsdl and I can't get any tools to correctly create the service objects for me to use.  This has been extremely frustrating.

Comment: Frustrating :/ Well what you can do is to regenerate the XSD from your example with visual studio(object inside soap:body only), then build a WSDL from types definied in XSD. You can also create service contract manually (well that's painful too)

Comment: I’m fairly new to this soap and xml stuff. I’ve always been able to leverage the VS tools to generate the services for me. This is the first time I’ve had to get this far in the weeds. I’m not necessarily sure how to do the work arounds suggesting.